# Searching for an Asian flight that provides a facility for divers to not pay an extra fee from Tehran to Phuket

Tags: airlines, thailand, gear, asia, phuket

Is there any airline with Asian flights between Tehran (Iran) and Phuket that provides a special facility for divers to not pay an extra fee for their heavy diving equipments? 
I have heard something like this for divers who have their equipment with themselves for first time and for the second time and more they have to pay extra fees!

Any Asian flight would be OK. The flight does not need to be non-stop.

Comment: OK, cleaned it up a bit, and clarified what you meant (I hope - sorry if I got it wrong).  (You didn't relly mean "dollars" did you?)  // AFAIK, most divers rent tank and weights from the dive shop, rather than travel with them.

Comment: @uncovery I agree about the "first time"; that whole sentence seemed odd to me, so I left it (don't know what he meant). // Otherwise .. "facility" is a little awkward here, but it is valid (so I left it - this is not ELU) - not all "facilities" are physical, 'means' would be synonymous with this usage. "Exception" would have conveyed his meaning, too (although it is not synonymous).  /  It is *accurate* to say that Tehran and Phuket are in Asia. It is not very *precise*, and I don't see how it's relevant.

Comment: It is not about weights and tanks!.. Who carry them with him/herself?!.. :)) .. BCD and regulator, fins and mask and wetsuits all are heavy in sum. A divemaster has to have his/her own equipment. For first time means for first time not second time that you have your diving equipments with yourself in the flight and searching for a special facility to not pay extra fee for them. Surely this question is for whom have enough knowledge about flights,diving and geography. Thanks!

Comment: IDK, fins, suit and maybe BCD could be picked up at the shop.   But yeah, hopefully someone will be able to give you an answer - it sounds like a strange exception/'facility' to me (that there would be a difference from the first time to the next), but maybe I'll learn something!   It would probably help if you could figure out where you heard about this before, and post a link, or some information ...

Comment: @hunter2 Yes! I can/have to buy them in the destination but what about return?!.. I have to carry them!.. And again yes! It is strange for me too but I have heard it for first time from some of Turkish divers in Turkey. Unfortunately I have no contact with them anymore and do not have their e mails or phones. Ok! I will try to find it but if I had it, I had the answer too. Do not you think so?.. &^) ..

Comment: Ah, yes - I see your point. (To be fair, lots of people leave out details) // Is it possible the story got a little mixed up (language barrier, eg)?  Maybe they booked some kind of package that sent the gear with them, or even included travel?  Or that they sweet-talked airline personnel, "oh, I didn't know, we were on vacation and didn't plan all this luggage" ..or just that the plane was empty enough (that's happened to me - no *oversize* baggage fee, when I was underweight otherwise and the plane wasn't full - years ago, though)

Answer (score 5):

I checked the Wikipedia entries for [Tehran Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tehran_Imam_Khomeini_International_Airport) and [Phuket Airport](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phuket_International_Airport), but I think the direct flight from IKA-> HKT on Mahan Air has been terminated.

That works in your favor, in my opinion, as Qatar Airways seems most friendly to divers. You can fly from Tehran to Phuket via [Doha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doha_International_Airport).

From the [Qatar Airways website](http://support.qatarairways.com/entries/381230-What-if-I-want-to-check-in-):

Qatar Airlines:

> *Qatar Airways allows extra baggage allowance only for the below listed sporting equipments... Regardless of class of travel, an additional complimentary 10Kgs will be allowed...*
>
> ***Scuba Diving Equipment:***
>   *Which consists of suit, vest, socks, mask, shoes, torch, webs, knife, oxygen cylinder and a regulator. Diving cylinders must be empty.*